# How to properly call AWS.CloudFront.Signer in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-cloudfront

I tried to get a signed URL in a node.js app, my code is shown below.

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require("fs");
var options = { keypairId: 'keypairId', privateKeyPath: 'privateKeyPath', expireTime: (new Date().getTime() + 3000) };
var url = 'cloudfrontURL' + objectpath;
const key = fs.readFileSync('privateKeyPath').toString("ascii");
const id = 'keypairId';
const signer = new AWS.CloudFront.Signer(id, key);
const params = {
 url: url,
 expires: 1538999532,
};
signer.getSignedUrl(params, function (err, data) {
 if (err) { console.log(err) }
 console.log(data);
});
```

but I am getting an error, which is shown below

AWS.CloudFront.Signer is not a constructor

What is the reason for this?

Comment: You are using a current version of the SDK?

Comment: Thanks Michael,I updated the version and it works fine

Comment: Hi Michael, It is not working after enabled CloudFront viewer access restriction?